# Change size of regular font (e.g. in paragraph or link) with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I can see the very useful `fs-*` classes [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#font-size):

[image]

The problem I have is these only apply to h1 down to h6, but no smaller.

E.g. I can't change the size (smaller) of regular text inside `<p>` tags or in on a bootstrap link e.g `<p class="link-secondary">Very Small Link</p>`.

Is there a way to change the font size of regular text (not headers) using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way: use [bootstrap's typography inline elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/#inline-text-elements). Example

```
<p>Regular text</p>
<p class="small">Smaller text</p>
```

[image]

From the bootstrap docs:

> (The 'small' class) is meant to be treated as fine print.